# how to replace values in particular DF column depending on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a DataFrame like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : [x,x,x,x,x],
    'B' : [1,2,1,1,2]        
    })
```

I would like to replace x by y where df['B'] == 2
I know there are lots of ways but what is the shortest code to accomplish this? I believe np.where is one way but can it change value (or overwrite variable) based on values in another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternatives select by both conditions or using `replace` with select by one condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'A' : ['x'] * 5,
    'B' : [1,2,1,1,2]        
    })

df.loc[df.B.eq(2) & df.A.eq('x'), 'A'] = 'y'
print (df)
   A  B
0  x  1
1  y  2
2  x  1
3  x  1
4  y  2
```

Or:

```
df.A = df.A.mask(df.B.eq(2) & df.A.eq('x'), 'y')
```

Or:

```
df.A = df.A.mask(df.B.eq(2), df.A.replace('x','y'))
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['B'].eq(2), 'A'] = df['A'].replace('x', 'y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['B'] == 2, 'A'] = df.loc[df['B'] == 2, 'A'].replace('x', 'y')
>>> df
   A  B
0  x  1
1  y  2
2  x  1
3  x  1
4  y  2
>>>
```